# Need help understanding this simplification/optimization for a very basic GLSL shader

Tags: shader, glsl, mathematics, optimisation, optimization

i'm currently following a tutorial on youtube to get started with computer graphics (shaders) and it contains the following GLSL code:

```
void mainImage(out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord) {
    vec2 uv = fragCoord / iResolution.xy * 2. - 1.; // Normalize & center
    uv.x *= iResolution.x / iResolution.y; // Account for aspect ratio

    float d = length(uv);
    fragColor = vec4(d, d, d, 1.0);
}
```

However, in the tutorial the two first lines are simplified into:

```
    vec2 uv = (fragCoord * 2.0 - iResolution.xy) / iResolution.y;
```

I can't understand how this simplification is made.
I think I found the first part by merging both expressions in one:

```
    vec2 uv = (fragCoord * 2.0 / iResolution.xy - 1.0) * vec2(iResolution.x / iResolution.y, 1.0);
```

If possible, **could anyone provide me with the detailed steps of this simplification** please ?

This is a picture of the expected result:[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

`fragCoord` and `iResolution` are both of `vec2` type and the **vector division is element-wise**. So the first step get you:

```cpp
vec2 uv = fragCoord / iResolution.xy * 2. - 1.; // Normalize & center
// uv.x = fragCoord.x / iResolution.x * 2. - 1.
```

In the second step, we multiply `uv.x` by `iResolution.x / iResolution.y` so basically:

```cpp
uv.x = (fragCoord.x / iResolution.x * 2. - 1.) * iResolution.x / iResolution.y
// this can be simplified to the following since iResolution.x is cancelled out.
uv.x = fragCoord.x / iResolution.y * 2. - iResolution.x / iResolution.y
```

You will find the `uv.x` is exactly the x field of:

```cpp
vec2 uv = (fragCoord * 2.0 - iResolution.xy) / iResolution.y;
// uv.x = (fragCoord.x * 2.0 - iResolution.x) / iResolution.y
// = fragCoord.x / iResolution.y * 2.0 - iResolution.x / iResolution.y;
```

which is the simplified version in the tutorial.